# How to rotate button element background but not the button itself

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background, background-image

I am trying to rotate the background-image inside of my button but I seem to only be getting the background color I specify, not the background-image over the top. I have a transparent part of the photo to create an arch-like look on the button.
Here is my css:

```
#sign-in-button > div > button.btn.btn-default {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #da1a32; 
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;'

/*  background-image: url('/images/arch-red-flip.png'); */
/*  background-repeat: no-repeat; */
/*  background-size: cover; */  
}

#sign-in-button > div > button.btn.btn-default:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: cover;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    background-image: url('/images/arch-red-flip.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
 }

<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="right-border">
        <div class="row" id="sign-in-button">
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">SIGN IN</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code for your image is commented. For the :before image, you have to set a width and a height because it is empty; with no content. So width and height to 0. So display:block on it, and set it a width and a height

Comment: @AlexVand I set a display:block, width, and height on my :before and still nothing. The image is commented out due to it being set on the :before to rotate it. Is that not correct?

Comment: Note though that if this is an **actual** `<button>` or `<input>` then it may not support pseudo-elements in your browser.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have added the html code to make it more clear.

Comment: Aha...it's a typo...you're using `background-image` instead of `background`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using the `background` **shorthand** notation on `background-image` property.

```css
button.btn.btn-default {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #da1a32;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3em;
}

button.btn.btn-default::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded) 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">SIGN IN</button>
```

Note however that the image will be on top of the text and using `z-index:-1` will cause the pseudo-element to be placed *under* the button...I would recommend an internal span to solve this.

```css
button.btn.btn-default {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #da1a32;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3em;
}

button.btn.btn-default span {
  position: relative;
}

button.btn.btn-default::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded) 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span>SIGN IN</span></button>
```

Comment: is it possible to achieve this with the normal sized bootstrap button? I tried setting height and width to auto but it seems to be the same as 100% or do I just have to play with it to get the right size?

Comment: Should be fine. The typo was the problem,,,not the button size as far as I can tell.